# Ticks on track container. Html5 slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to reove these aesthetically unpleasing "ticks" from my slider track.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uua6w.png

This is how it appears in chrome and firefox and how I would like it to appear in explorer too:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPrmH.png

My HTML:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="55" class="slider" id="myRange">
```

The CSS I attempted (as suggested by Microsoft)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-ms-ticks-after

```
input[type="range"]::-ms-ticks-before,
input[type="range"]::-ms-ticks-after {
  display: none;
}
```

I noticed an element created by the IE browser #ticks_on_track_container is responsible for these "ticks"/lines. When I inspect element and write a style rule like this:

```
#ticks_on_track_container {
  display: none;
}
```

It works and the lines dissapear! But when I do that either inline underneath my HTML or in my main.css there is no difference and the lines persist. I can only remove them using inspect element.

Please can you help me :S

EDIT:
It looks like Internet Explorer appends a whole new html file onto the end of mine!? How can I edit the styles of this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMiqp.png

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with the following css:

```
.slider::-ms-track {
  color: transparent;
}
```